# Android Studio: Bug with Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK

Tags: java, android

I didn't found my "bug" in another question, so I really need help.

In my app, I have this code:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MONTH);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.YEAR);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.HOUR);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.MINUTE);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.SECOND);
    frase(calendar);
```

This code is inside onCreate and the code below is below onCreate();

```
     public void frase(Calendar calendar)
{
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    switch (day) {
        case Calendar.MONDAY:textView.setText(getText(R.string.segunda));break;
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:textView.setText(getText(R.string.terca));break;
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:textView.setText(getText(R.string.quarta));break;
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:textView.setText(getText(R.string.quinta));break;
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:textView.setText(getText(R.string.sexta));break;
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:textView.setText(getText(R.string.sabado));break;
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:textView.setText(getText(R.string.domingo));break;
    }
}
```

When I run the app, my emulator always returns me the Saturday case but the emulator day of the week is wednesday.

Comment: Where are you doing the getInstance() of calendar to take the actual date?

Comment: above the calendar.set()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Get Date**

```
public static String getDate() {
        Date myDate = new Date();
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(myDate);
       // new SimpleDateFormat("hh-mm-a").format(myDate);
        return date;
    }
```

> **Get day of week**

```
 public static int dayOfWeek(String date) {
        try {
            int day = 0;
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date now = simpleDateformat.parse(date);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(now);
            day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
            return day;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

> **Or simply call**
>
> getDay(new Date());

```
public static String getDay(Date date){

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    //System.out.println("DAY "+simpleDateFormat.format(date).toUpperCase());                       
    return simpleDateFormat.format(date).toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: and in get day of the week the String date will be getDate() right?

Comment: And the return String.valueOf(day) will return the day of the week like "WEDNESDAY"?

Comment: It will return 0-6 (Sun-Sat)

Comment: dayOfWeek was static String before xD. Thanks, your code is working.

Comment: In dayOfWeek method converting to SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); is redundant ,i did for my purpose.avoid that if you need not.

Comment: I didn't question your method, it's just funny that after I ask what would be the return, u change to int and wrote "it will return 0-6." xD and thanks again.

Comment: @AnoopM - why we are subtracting -1 from Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK?

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `Calendar.set()` is the value you want to that particular field defined by the first argument. Now you're setting constant values i.e. field index numbers, which makes no sense.

Remove your `set()` calls altogether. `Calendar.getInstance()` already returns an instance that is initialized to current date and time.

Comment: I've done it already, you didn't answer the question but you helped me cleaning up the code. Thanks!

Comment: So what was the question then, other than the implicit something along the lines of "this returns the wrong result, why"?

Comment: The question is why did my code always return Saturday, but Anoop M already answered.

Comment: I don't see where he answers that, only some alternative approaches around the same problem. But nevermind, you got your problem solved.

Comment: That's why I always talk about this problem as a bug.